# Spectrum Analyzer Sweep Times Sub 1-ms vs. EMI Test Receivers?

Tags: rf, spectrum-analyzer

I've got a Rigol DSA 832 and I have a client design that sends out a 1ms  message every 100ms.

The original protocol was a 1ms message every 6 seconds, which was darn near impossible to capture on our spectrum analyzer.

We had them change the packet structure to make some EMC measurements, but it's still like finding a needle in a haystack because the message duration is just 1 millisecond.

On my Rigol, once you change the span & resolution bandwidths it does not indicate sweep speeds lower then 1ms on the GUI.

Does anyone know if Rigol supports sweep speeds lower then 1 ms, even though the GUI doesn't indicate it?

But my main question: if you get into a formal test chamber with an EMI receiver does anyone know from-hands-on experience how quickly they can sweep say a 1MHz zone?

I feel like I would like a 100us type scan speed over a 1MHz to capture these stupid messages at this point.

Comment: some spectrum analyzers let you halt the sweeping, and simply monitor a fixed frequency.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf - do you mean like zero span?  The thing is that the we need to catch like 400kHz of this signal.  It's a royal mess.  I'm ready to bail on this thing. ;)

Comment: Most spectrum analysers have a RBW that can be dialled up to more then 400KHz, I know my ancient HP70000 has a IF module good for 10MHz bandwidth (Granted, does nothing good to the noise floor!)...  Probability of intercept is the magic term and it sounds like what you really want is a "Real time spectrum analyser" as opposed to a swept one.

Comment: @Dan Mills -- I think you are right on the on the "Real Time Spectrum Analyzer" vs. the swept.  I was reading on the real time spectrum analyzer and I think they sweep super fast (Nyquist theorem and all that jazz -- I'm not a super EE).  What's weird though since there is a regulatory goal to get this design certified, is that compliance test labs don't use real time spectrum analyzers since the results aren't used for the test reports!